# HEVC Transformation Optimization

Tags: hevc, video-codecs

I have been working on the HEVC project. I have recently asked some details with regards to Intra Prediction and it is more or less clarified. I was reading a book suggested by someone and it gives the details of the Transformation algorithm implemented in HEVC. I know that it uses Partial Butterfly in order to process data. However, would it be possible to implement via a different approach like say matrix multiplication and still the HEVC stream would be generated with no faults. What my question is that, whether if I modify the processing method for Transformation Module will it affect the process flow of HEVC Encoder on the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have implemented the Matrix Multiplication in place of Partial Butterfly for my solution. It works fine, the output looks good. I have confirmed that the PSNR SSIM and other parameters are good enough to confirm this for you.

Answer (score 1):

The transform has to comply with the HEVC standard, but how you implement it exactly is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It just implementation issue, Matrix Multiplication can optimization by using other method like SIMD.